# Airflow XCOM_PUSH does not work with ConsumeFromTopicOperator 2.x

Tags: apache-kafka, airflow

Airflow `xcom_push` from with a function called by `Kafka ConsumeFromTopicOperator` never allows you to push the value nor will any other task be able to retrieve it.

If you try to push it it results in runtime error, if you simply 'return my_value' nothing else can:

```
ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='CONSUME_FROM_TOPIC_02')
```

It always results in None.

Example:
'''
`
from airflow_provider_kafka.operators.consume_from_topic import ConsumeFromTopicOperator

```
def await_function(message):
      ctx = get_current_context()
      ti = ctx\["ti"\]
      msg = message.value()
      my_value = msg\['my_cool_value'\]
      ti.xcom_push(key='data', value=my_value)
      return my_value

ConsumeFromTopicOperator(
                     dag=dag,
                     task_id="CONSUME_FROM_TOPIC_02",
                     topics=\['my.Events'\],
                     apply_function="this_dag_file_name.await_function",
                     consumer_config=kafka_config,
                     commit_cadence="end_of_batch",
                     poll_timeout=20,
                     max_messages=1,
                     max_batch_size=100,
                    )
```

`
'''

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and overcame by creating a `customConsumeFromTopicOperator` which passed the context to the `apply_function`
The context is already available to the execute method, it wasn't being passed.

This approach worked for me as I was able to set out xcom manually.

```
class CustomConsumeFromTopicOperator(ConsumeFromTopicOperator):

def __init__(
        self,
        **kwargs: Any,
) -> None:
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def execute(self, context) -> Any:

    consumer = KafkaConsumerHook(topics=self.topics, kafka_config_id=self.kafka_config_id).get_consumer()

    if isinstance(self.apply_function, str):
        self.apply_function = import_string(self.apply_function)

    if isinstance(self.apply_function_batch, str):
        self.apply_function_batch = import_string(self.apply_function_batch)

    if self.apply_function:
        apply_callable = partial(
            self.apply_function, *self.apply_function_args, **self.apply_function_kwargs  # type: ignore
        )

    if self.apply_function_batch:
        apply_callable = partial(
            self.apply_function_batch,  # type: ignore
            *self.apply_function_args,
            **self.apply_function_kwargs,
        )

    messages_left = self.max_messages

    while self.read_to_end or (
            messages_left > 0
    ):  # bool(True > 0) == True in the case where self.max_messages isn't set by the user

        if not isinstance(messages_left, bool):
            batch_size = self.max_batch_size if messages_left > self.max_batch_size else messages_left
        else:
            batch_size = self.max_batch_size

        msgs = consumer.consume(num_messages=batch_size, timeout=self.poll_timeout)
        messages_left -= len(msgs)

        if not msgs:  # No messages + messages_left is being used.
            self.log.info("Reached end of log. Exiting.")
            break

        if self.apply_function:
            for m in msgs:
                apply_callable(m, context=context)

        if self.apply_function_batch:
            apply_callable(msgs, context=context)

        if self.commit_cadence == "end_of_batch":
            self.log.info("committing offset at %s", self.commit_cadence)
            consumer.commit()

    if self.commit_cadence:
        self.log.info("committing offset at %s", self.commit_cadence)
        consumer.commit()

    consumer.close()

    return
```